# Python extract only links with a string and follow links with CAPITAL letters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is a multi part question so my apologies, I'll try to keep it straight forward.

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract links from a web page, here are the code and results

[image: Please see image for code and results]

Questions:

1. I want to exclude links that do NOT have `airportname=XXX`
2. I then want to follow the links with `airportname=XXX` and search for a string of text on the following pages.

Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: Don't use images of code, please insert the code at the question

Comment: I tried for about 30 minutes trying to do what "Help" suggested to no avail. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

For first part

You can use Regex

```
 import re

 XXX=[]
    for result in results:
        match = re.match( r'(airportname=\w\w\w)', result)
        if match:
            XXX.append(match.group(1))
```

For Second Part

```
 for url in results:
         #hit the url and get the response as text and just search the text for the query string as in part 1
```

Comment: Hi Mithilesh, a kind thank you for your quick response. The thing is, the XXX is different for each link (and there are about 100), these for for U.S. 3 digit airport codes. Eg. Dallas would be DFW, Los Angeles would be LAX etc.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this task, the actually URL would be needed. To determine if the links are suitable, the following approach can be used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.website.com/airports')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)

for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    href = link['href']

    if re.search('airportname=\w\w\w$', href):
        print href
```

Next, you would need to create a full URL based on the `href` you get.